# Flex: How to add a tab close button for TabNavigator component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'd like to have a `TabNavigator` component that has a close button for some of the tabs. How do I do that?  
It seems that the `TabNavigator` component does not allow (or I could not find)  extensibility of this form.
Help. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should take a look at the SuperTabNavigator component from the [FlexLib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) project:

- [SuperTabNavigator example](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/SuperTabNavigator_Sample.swf)
- [SuperTabNavigator documentation](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/SuperTabNavigator.html)
- [FlexLib Component list](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList)

If you don't want all of the tabs to have close buttons (I understand from the question that you don't) it looks like you could use the [setClosePolicyForTab()](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/SuperTabNavigator.html#setClosePolicyForTab()) method for specifying which tabs you want to have them.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Based Component

[**flexwiz** spark-tabs-with-close-button](http://blog.flexwiz.net/spark-tabs-with-close-button/)