# How do I style or skin the TabNavigator buttons?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'd like to add an icon and a close button to the TabNavigator in Flex 4 but can't find any examples online (all are for Flex 3).

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="firstViewStack" 
                 width="100%"
                 height="100%"
                 clipContent="true">

    <s:NavigatorContent label="FIRST TAB"  >
        <s:Group width="100%" />
    </s:NavigatorContent>

</mx:TabNavigator>
```

Comment: Use SuperTabNavigator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67516/flex-how-to-add-a-tab-close-button-for-tabnavigator-component

Comment: I think that one is only for mx based components :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZOMGWTH?!?!?! This took way too long to figure out. This is how you set the default Tab skin:

```
mx|Tab {
    skin:ClassReference("mx.skins.spark.TabSkin");
}
```

You can copy that skin into your own project and make modifications as needed:

Here are some examples. This modifies all Tabs in all TabNavigators:

```
mx|Tab {
    skin:ClassReference("mySkins.MyTabSkin");
}
```

To skin only one TabNavigator:

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabBarNavigator" styleName="myTabNavigator">

    <s:NavigatorContent label="First Tab"  >
            <s:Group width="100%" />
    </s:NavigatorContent>

    <s:NavigatorContent label="Second Tab">
        <s:Group height="100%" width="100%" />
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:TabNavigator>


<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace utils "com.flexcapacitor.utils.*";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

    .myTabNavigator {
        tabStyleName: "myTabs";
    }

    .myTabs {
        skin:ClassReference("mySkins.MyTabSkin");
    }
</fx:Style>
```

This works with Flex 4.6 and the Spark theme.

**Update 2:**
Here are some more notable styles:

```
.myTabs {
    skin:ClassReference("skins.SolidFillTabSkin");
    fillAlpha:1;
    borderAlpha:1;
    cornerRadius:0;
    /*color:#FF0000;
    chromeColor: #00FF00;
    textRollOverColor: #0000FF;
    textSelectedColor: #00FF00;*/
    textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETextField"); /* default is mx.core.UITextField*/
}
```

The textSelectedColor almost never fires. So there is never a selected text color. Also, the text is moved down when the tab is selected!

So below is a new skin where the text doesn't move down. You'll probably need to set the text and fill colors in the skin if you don't want to use the defaults although you can use chromeColor to set the fill color. This skin supports cornerRadius and borderAlpha,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
Apache License 2.0.
-->

<!--- The Spark skin class for the tabs of the MX TabNavigator container. 

How to use: 

With a specific TabNavigator:  

.myTabNavigator {
    tabStyleName: "myTabs";
}

.myTabs {
    skin:ClassReference("mySkins.MyTabSkin");
}

Applied to all Tabs in all TabNavigators:  

mx|Tab {
    skin:ClassReference("com.flexcapacitor.skins.SolidFillTabNavigatorButtonSkin");
    fillAlpha:1;
    borderAlpha:1;
    cornerRadius:0;
    /*color:#FF0000;
    chromeColor: #00FF00;
    textRollOverColor: #0000FF;
    textSelectedColor: #00FF00;*/
    textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETextField"); /* default is mx.core.UITextField*/
}

@see mx.containers.TabNavigator

@langversion 3.0
@playerversion Flash 10
@playerversion AIR 1.5
@productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             minWidth="21" minHeight="21"
             alpha.disabledStates="0.5">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import mx.core.IUITextField;
        import mx.core.mx_internal;

        use namespace mx_internal;

        private var cornerRadius:Number = 0;

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        /**
         * COPIED FROM TabBarButtonSkin.mxml
         *  @private
         *  The cornerRadius style is specified by the TabBar, not the button itself.   
         * 
         *  Rather than bind the corner radius properties of the s:Rect's in the markup 
         *  below to hostComponent.owner.getStyle("cornerRadius"), we reset them here, 
         *  each time a change in the value of the style is detected.  Note that each 
         *  corner radius property is explicitly initialized to the default value of 
         *  the style; the initial value of the private cornerRadius property.
         */
        private function updateCornerRadius():void
        {
            var cr:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
            if (cornerRadius != cr)
            {
                cornerRadius = cr;
                fill.topLeftRadiusX = cornerRadius;
                fill.topRightRadiusX = cornerRadius;
            }
        }

        /**
         * COPIED FROM TabBarButtonSkin.mxml
         *  @private
         *  This function creates the path data used by borderTop and selectedHighlight.
         */
        private function createPathData(isBorder:Boolean):String
        {
            var left:Number = 0;
            var right:Number = width;
            var top:Number = 0.5;
            var bottom:Number = height;

            var a:Number = cornerRadius * 0.292893218813453;
            var s:Number = cornerRadius * 0.585786437626905;

            // If the path is for the highlight,
            // Draw the vertical part of the selected tab highlight that's rendered 
            // with alpha=0.07.  The s:Path is configured to include only the left and 
            // right edges of an s:Rect, along with the top left,right rounded corners. 
            // Otherwise, we draw a full path.
            var path:String = "";
            path +=  "M " + left + " " + bottom;
            path += " L " + left + " " + (top + cornerRadius);
            path += " Q " + left + " " + (top + s) + " " + (left + a) + " " + (top + a);
            path += " Q " + (left + s) + " " + top + " " + (left + cornerRadius) + " " + top;

            if (isBorder)
                path += " L " + (right - cornerRadius) + " " + top;
            else
                path += " M " + (right - cornerRadius) + " " + top;

            path += " Q " + (right - s) + " " + top + " " + (right - a) + " " + (top + a);
            path += " Q " + right + " " + (top + s) + " " + right + " " + (top + cornerRadius);
            path += " L " + right + " " + bottom;

            return path;
        }

        /**
         * COPIED FROM TabBarButtonSkin.mxml
         *  @private
         *  The borderTop s:Path is just a s:Rect with the bottom edge left out.
         *  Given the rounded corners per the cornerRadius style, the result is 
         *  roughly an inverted U with the specified width, height, and cornerRadius.
         * 
         *  Circular arcs are drawn with two curves per flash.display.Graphics.GraphicsUtil.
         */        
        private function updateBorderTop(width:Number, height:Number):void
        {
            // Generate path data and lay it out. The path is not being layout by the default BasicLayout of this skin
            // since we excluded it from the layout.
            var path:String = createPathData(true);
            borderTop.data = path;
            borderTop.setLayoutBoundsSize(width, height, false);
            borderTop.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, 0, false);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number) : void
        {
            updateCornerRadius();
            updateBorderTop(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var button:Button = owner as Button;// is the Button
            var textField:IUITextField = button.getTextField();
            var label:String = button.label;

            // if you want to use your own text field hide the other one here
            if (textField) {
                //textField.includeInLayout = false;
                textField.visible = false;
            }

            if (labelDisplay) {
                labelDisplay.text = label;
            }

            var borderAlpha:Number = button.getStyle("borderAlpha");
            if (!isNaN(borderAlpha)) {
                borderTop.alpha = borderAlpha;
                if (lineAlongTheBottom) {
                    lineAlongTheBottom.alpha = borderAlpha;
                }
            }

            var fillAlpha:Number = button.getStyle("fillAlpha");
            if (!isNaN(fillAlpha)) {
                fillColor.alpha = fillAlpha;
            }

            var fillColorValue:Number = button.getStyle("fillColor");
            if (!isNaN(fillColorValue)) {
                //fillColor.color = fillColorValue;
            }

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" />
        <s:State name="down" />
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates"/>
        <s:State name="selectedUp" stateGroups="selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="selectedOver" stateGroups="selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="selectedDown" stateGroups="selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="selectedDisabled" stateGroups="disabledStates, selectedStates" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- layer 1: fill -->
    <s:Rect id="fill" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="0" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="fillColor" 
                          color="0xFFFFFF" 
                          color.selectedStates="0xECEEEE"
                          color.over="0xECEEEE" 
                          alpha="1" />
<!--            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xE4E4E4" color.over="0xCACACA"
                                 color.selectedStates="0xFFFFFF"
                                 alpha="1" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xA1A1A1" color.over="0x878787"
                                 color.selectedStates="0xE4E4E4" 
                                 alpha="1" />
            </s:LinearGradient>-->
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>


    <!-- layer 4: border - unselected only -->
    <s:Line id="lineAlongTheBottom" left="0" right="0" bottom="0" excludeFrom="selectedStates" >
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x696969" alpha="1" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Line>

    <!--- Set includeInLayout="false" as we regenerate the path data and lay out the path in
    the updateDisplayList() override and we don't want it to affect measurement. @private
    -->
    <s:Path id="borderTop" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" includeInLayout="false">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.5625"
                                 alpha.down="0.6375"
                                 alpha.selectedStates="0.6375" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                 alpha="0.75" 
                                 alpha.down="0.85"
                                 alpha.selectedStates="0.85" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Path>

    <!-- layer 8: text -->
    <!--- @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay -->
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             visible="true"
             textAlign="center"
             verticalAlign="middle"
             maxDisplayedLines="1" 
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="2"
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>
</s:SparkSkin>
```